# if text area not empty then stop user action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want a jquery code to check if the text area is empty or not?? .

If it's not empty and the user tries to refresh the page or logout user should get a dialog asking to confirm exit

**Javascript**

```
     <script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ta = $('#text_area').val();
        if (ta != "") {

            $("#dialog-confirm").html("You have unsaved data on this page. Do you wish to ?");
            $('#dialog-confirm').attr('title', 'Confirm Exit').dialog({
                buttons : {
                    'Leave this page' : function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');

                        $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");

                    },
                    'Stay on this page' : function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
                    }

                },
                closeOnEscape : false,
                draggable : false,
                resizable : false,
                show : 'fade',
                modal : true,
                width : '500px',
                maxHeight : 500,
                open : function (event, ui) {

                    $(this).parent().children().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function () {
                        $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id = "text_area"> </textarea>
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
```

**Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

You should be listening to `window.onbeforeunload` event. For example:

**Updated**
here's a more elaborate example as one html file: (read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "You have made changes to textarea";
        if ($("#myTextArea").val()) {
            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     //Gecko + IE
            return confirmationMessage;                                //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
        }

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea name="" id="myTextArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please help me with an example .